# find cache hit rate for direct mapped cache memory

Tags: digital-logic, computers, computer-architecture, cache

I have this practice exam problem which I am having trouble with. I have gone over many slides but haven't been able to really get it. The question is

[image]

I currently have an 8 block main memory with 2 words in each block, as well as a 4 line cache which also has 2 words in each line. Im guessing this is wrong since the 4 bit addresses cant be split to get the block offset, line number and tag. Also I am not sure what I am meant to do past this step.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cache size is 4 blocks (@ 1 word each) => 2 bits for the line number. Now you need to find out how many of the given memory accesses cause cache misses because the data is not yet in the cache, or has been overwritten by another access since it was first loaded.

Comment: Is it possible to get more information ?, as I said I cant find much online.

Comment: Ok, so you have 2 bits to identify the cache line; those are usually the MSBs of the address. Hence, the cache line is identified by `address & 1100b`. Each cache line holds only one word, so no block offset needed. That means the remaining two bits of the address must be stored in the tag, i.e. `address & 0011b`. A cache miss occurrs whenever the tag for the requested address does not match the tag value of the corresponding cache line. With this information you can just simulate the given address sequence and find at which point(s) cache misses happen.

Comment: I am not sure how "I currently have an 8 block main memory with 2 words in ..." relates to the task of "finding the cache hit rate".

Comment: @HannoBinder: You have the index and tag mixed up. In a direct-mapped cache, the cache line is selected by the LSBs of the address (two bits, in this case), and the cache tag is all of the remaining high-order bits of the address.

Comment: yeah everything i had seen had the lsb as the line number so used that and got 30% hit rate. I had 8 block main memory with 2 words because i actually copied the wrong question the original was exactly the same but with cache size of 32bytes and block of 8 bytes.

Comment: Of course you're right, I mixed them up. Would severely impact chache efficiency that way. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: I worked it out and believe i got the right answer. But my original issue was with basically the same question except the cache size is 32 bytes, block size is 8 bytes and everything else being the same.

In this case i get 2 words per cache line in which case a 4 bit address doesn't suffice since I need two bits for line, two bits for tag and 1 for word. Is this a mistake in the question or is there a way to do it.

Comment: "got 30% hit rate" - You may want to re-count. I'm getting a different number.

Comment: yeah your right its 40%. Heres the original question

<a href="http://imgur.com/8uz9Zfi"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8uz9Zfi.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: "in which case a 4 bit address doesn't suffice" - It's not the cache that defines the address width, it's the address width of the main memory that defines the cache addressing. So if the memory has 4 bits address width, the cache can never have more address bits than that. Otherwise, the cache would be larger than main memory. Remember how and in which order the size of each part of the (line,tag,word) tuple is determined.

Comment: in the question though when they say 4 bit address aren't they referring to the tag/line#/offs number ?

Comment: ok, I think I understand what you where saying but in the  two questions given no information about the size of main memory is given (or needed) correct ? Since they have given the address as 4 bits you can just simulate use it any values and get the hit/miss ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. - And yes, the 4 bit address is split into those 3 parts line, tag, and offset; or the other way around: the number of bits for line+tag+offset must equal the address width.